# Access Form: Invalid ControlSource

Tags: ms-access

In my Access Form I have a `Text Box` that should have this value:

```
SELECT [QueryOne].[Company] FROM [QueryOne] WHERE ([QueryOne].[ID] = "1000"
```

So, I wrote in the `ControlSource` of this textbox the following string:

```
= ( SELECT [QueryOne].[Company] FROM [QueryOne] WHERE ([QueryOne].[ID] = "1000" )
```

but the result that I get is that the `textbox.value` is `#Name?`. Maybe this string should not be in the `ControlSource`?

Answer (score 1):

Use DLookup:

```
=DLookup("[Company]"), "[QueryOne]", "[ID] = '1000'")
```

or more probably `ID` isn't a text column, then

```
=DLookup("[Company]"), "[QueryOne]", "[ID] = 1000")
```

Answer (score 1):

Access text boxes cannot be directly used to execute SQL. You can however call a function from the text box by setting it as the `Control Source` and display the result. Access offers a number of functions which can be used to retrieve data from a database. `DlookUp` should do what you require here:

```
=DLookUp("[Company]","[QueryOne]","ID='1000'")
```

You probably want to be able to enter the company ID to return the name. To do that, change the function to refer to another input textbox on your form like so (obviously just change the form and text box names to match your elements):

```
=DLookUp("[Company]","[QueryOne]","[ID]='" & [Forms]![Form1].[txtCompanyID].[Value] & "'")
```

Of course, if you are doing anything more than the most trivial of lookups, the correct way of doing this would be to set up a `Record Source` for the form and set the text box `Control Source` to a field from this dataset.

Comment: As Andre pointed out in his answer, if your ID column is not a text data type you will need to remove the single quotes surrounding the value being looked up (e.g. ID='1000' becomes ID=1000)